# Adobe Acrobat Reader don't zoom out the page enough in "one page" mode

Tags: adobe-reader, adobe-acrobat

I'm using Adobe Acrobat Reader version 9.4 under Debian Lenny. I'm experiencing a problem: when I push the "Show one page at a time" button, I expect the page to zoom such that pressing PgUp/PgDn would turn to the next/previous page. However, the zoom seems to be not enough - very thin bottom portion of the page doesn't fit inside the reader window, and pressing PgUp/PgDn gives the jitter of the same page, and I have to push twice to get to the next page. It is even worse in continuous page mode - a roll of pages begin to be non-synced with window boundaries, ending up with page break right in the middle of the view after several turns of the pages.

This behaviour doesn't occur on windows version - I have a page properly zoomed in single/continuous modes, so that turning the pages is performed as page-at-once, as intended.

How to make the Acrobat Reader fit the page to window properly?

Thats how it looks before pressing PgDn (notice the bottom edge of the "paper" hidden beneath the bottom window edge):

[image: Acrobat reader, one page / single page in effect, before PgDn]

Thats how it looks after pressing PgDn (notice the "paper" bottom edge emerged from beneath the window edge, while the "paper" upper edge hides behind the upper window edge, showing that the document window size is not enough to contain the whole page):

[image: Acrobat reader, one page / single page in effect, after PgDn]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry if my question is too dumb, but are you sure Acrobat Reader window is maximized?

Comment: It happens in any case - in maximized and in resized window. The page accommodates the Reader's window, but not enough to fit the interior, leaving a tiny strip below the bottom window edge.

Comment: See the question updated with the screenshots illustrating the problem.

Comment: Weird... One only thing I can think of is it is not considering internally some of those toolbars. For example, the tab. (just bellow the text menu, with the X icon) . can you just check in preferences if disabling/hiding several toolbars, but specially tabs, you gain that exact chunk ? Edit: In Windows, I don't remember seing  that tab...Might be new feature, yet to be polished..try disabling...

Comment: This tab appears from "Open documents in tabs" option in Preferences-Documents. Disabling it gives nothing - paper is still tiny-cropped by the window.

Comment: More ideas... The font size, I am not really a  mac user, I don't know if you can change general system font size, but if you did, that might be... Also, trying hiding in prefs the menu bar and the icons bar.

Comment: Got it! It goes from the Page Display - Resolution option. When it's set to "Use system setting", it detects 93dpi, while in the system display preferences it's set to 92. When I switch to "Use custom resolution", the page squeezes a bit to exactly fit the window! Even if I put the same (wrong) 93 dpi in custom resolution, the page still fits! Looks like there's a rounding error in the program that mismatches the canvas and window sizes in dpi-to-pixel calculation.

Comment: Finally... :) It'll make much more comfortable reading :)

Answer (score 1):

In *Preferences* > *Page display* > *Resolution:*, don't use the system resolution but a custom resolution (slightly) smaller than the system resolution (i.e. from 93 pixels/inch to 90 pixels/inch). That should work with a little tweaking. It worked on my iMac with Snow Leopard and Acrobat X Professional 10.1.4.